# Update child product's "Manage Stock" when parent is changed

Tags: configurable-product, stock

I’m looking for a way to update “Manage Stock” on all child products of a Configurable Product when the parent is updated.  ie When a parent is toggled to “No” for “Manage Stock”, I would like it to set all the Associated Simple Products to “No” as well.  Currently, Magento (EE 1.13) does not do this for us, and we have to change all the children individually.  Not much of an issue when there is just a couple of children, but we have many configurable products with 50 or more associated products.  Hopefully, someone knows of a quick and easy way to do this (like an extension or setting), and can save us a lot of clicking.  TIA

Comment: As Fabian said, you will need to listen to an event and hook onto it to trigger the saving of all of associated simple products. It is worth noting that, when this is set up, saving a configurable product with 50 or more child product will take quite some time to complete..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly is your problem here? How to do it?

Implement an observer
Listen to `cataloginventory_stock_item_save_before` check whether the product is `configurable` and `origData` against `data` and if the status changed.

If yes, get all the associated products and update the stock items too.

Comment: Well, I was hoping for a setting or extension way of doing it, as my programming skills aren't the best.  In lieu of those options, I guess I don't have much of a choice...save for just manually doing each child.  I'll use your suggestion as a starting point.  Thanks.

Comment: Ah ok, no sorry, I don't know any extension (I don't know much extensions...) good luck